# Should I use an apache redirect or a Drupal redirect

Tags: performance, apache, drupal, redirect

I am debating between using an apache redirect vs a Drupal redirect, and I am wondering what the best practice would be. The Drupal redirect appeals to me because it would allow non-technical content editors to add their own redirects. I suspect the downside is that every redirect added that way needs to fire up the entire Drupal stack, as opposed to just adding a direct apache redirect. Is there a big difference, or is it negligible in terms of a performance hit, etc. The site is fairly high traffic, but not to the point of using Akamai; several million non concurrent page views a month handled by varnish is doing just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming an "Apache redirect" you mentioned in your question is a redirect set in the .htaccess or Apache settings files, and a "Drupal redirect" is a custom redirect that you can create using Redirect module.

Redirect module implements `hook_url_inbound_alter` and `hook_init` to perform the redirect, which require a full Drupal bootstrap, but the good thing is that if there is a redirect exists, the redirect will happen immediately and no further processing will be done - for example, `hook_page_alter`, and many other preprocess hooks will not be executed at all.

Apache redirect would be the best way if you have fewer redirects (<50 IMO). 
If your redirects should follow a specific pattern, for example, if all your redirects' source is `http://example.com/old-folder/*`, just create a folder and add redirects to `old-folder/.htaccess`.